# Get exact image dimensions with matplotlib and bbox_inches='tight'

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I plot a series of figures and save them via savefig as png files (where savefig gets dpi=100 as an argument). The aspect ratio and resolution is previously defined within `plt.figure(figsize=(10.24, 10.24), dpi=100)`, which should result in images of exactly 1024x1024 pixels. I use `bbox_inches='tight'` as well as `plt.tight_layout()`, but I still get image dimensions that vary about a few pixels from one image to the next, depending on the axis labels it seems.
Did I miss something? How do I get the exact same image dimensions for every file without losing `bbox_inches='tight'`? Using matplotlib 1.3.1.